# Change color on element more than one time

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the color of an element depending on where you are on the site. I have liked it to one anchor point and it is working. But i want it to change color more than one time. Every time it reaches the anchor point #intro i want it to be white and when it reaches the anchor point #portfolio i want it to go black again. How can i make this work?

This is what i have so far:

```
function scroll_style() {
   var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
   var div_top = $('#portfolio').offset().top;

   if (window_top > div_top){
      $('#nav-icon4 span').css({"background":"#000"});

   }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(scroll_style);
    scroll_style();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `else { $('#nav-icon4 span').css({"background":"#FFF"}); } ` after your `if` statement?

Comment: Yes and that works fine when i scroll upp to #intro but when i continue to scroll down to next point #experience i also want it to go back to white and when i hit the las anchor point i want it to go black again and that doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not understanding the last anchor part, but to get it back to white after scrolling to next point, you have to compare against element bottom position too. And if not `true`, revert to white.

```
function scroll_style() {
   var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
   var $element = $('#portfolio');
   var div_top = $element.offset().top;
   var div_bottom = div_top + $element.outerHeight();
   var $icon = $('#nav-icon4 span');

   if (window_top > div_top && window_top < div_bottom){
      $icon.css({"background":"#000"});
   }
   else{
      $icon.css({"background":"#FFF"});
   }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(scroll_style);
    scroll_style();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's way more complex than you need. Skip using JS logic and just use the CSS nth-child() Selector or nth-of-type() Selector.